# I'm trying to refresh the document.title to get an inbox count display and having the following issues

Tags: javascript

The code I'm using is below, and I've researched it a bit on Stackoverflow. I've not found any solution to what I'm running into however.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function() {
  var x=document.getElementById("SUI-WelcomeLine-InboxNum");
  document.title = document.title + x.innerHTML;
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Everything works fine with what I have, except 1 thing. It posts the document title, but then repetitively posts the inbox number over and over. So I get the page title, for an example "My site" and then 111111111 when I have 1 message. How can I make it stop repeating the inbox count and refresh the document and inbox count as a whole?

Yep, I'm a noob.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is really confusing. What inbox? What is posting what? You have to remember that we don't know anything about your environment so it's hard to know what's happening. Try explaining more throughly so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Breno. Fortunately, I did get an answer though I'm certain I probably didn't give much to go on lol. I am very new. The SUI-WelcomeLine-InboxNum is the div where the inbox count on the site is displayed. Grabbing it's innerHTML is giving the count number to place in the document title. With the type of site I'm working on, server access is something that isn't granted for server sided scripting, nor do you get to see the source code there, so I really just didn't have a whole lot of information to give as far as how that number is being generated on the back end.

Comment: You did indeed. I guess it was my lack of knowledge in the subject that made it confusing. I apologize. By the way, if the answer Bergi gave you is correct and solved your problem, don't forget to click the checkmark next to it, so other people will know it did and he gets a small reputation boost for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var title = document.title;
setInterval(function() {
    var x=document.getElementById("SUI-WelcomeLine-InboxNum");
    document.title = title + x.innerText;
}, 3000);
```

However, I don't think you should do this task with a interval loop that regularly checks the inbox-element. Instead, let the script which updates the inbox element update the title, too.

Comment: Worked like a charm @Bergi. Can you give me some insight that'll stick in my brain as to what I did wrong initially so I can avoid it in the future?

Comment: You appended the content of the inbox element all 3 seconds to the current title (including appendages from before) and letting it grow and grow. My code saves the initial title in a variable, and only updates the document's title.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are constantly re-appending the string. `document.title = document.title + x.innerHTML;`

You ought to do something like this:

`document.title = "(" + count + ") Awesome Webapp";`

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I am very very new, so bare with me please. If var x is being appended in a loop like fashion, why isn't document.title doing the same thing?

Comment: `document.title = document.title + 1;` will ready the document title as it currently exists and append one; the next time it reads `document.title` it will have the previous '1' appended to it already and it will append another one anyway.